# What advantages do interfaces in a closed system bring except for making testing easier?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, mocking

I am at a point where I need to mock certain classes in order to test some parts of my software. But I can, of course, only mock them using an interface. For example if I have something like this (using Moq):

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void AddTestTaskTest()
    {
        TestTask assignable = null;
        var contextMock = new Mock<ApplicationDatabaseContext>();
        var appDbAdaptorMock = new Mock<ApplicationDatabaseAdaptor>(contextMock.Object);

        var dbOpMock = new Mock<TestTaskDbOperator>();

        void Action(TestTask t) => assignable = t;
        dbOpMock.Setup(p => p.Add(It.IsAny<TestTask>())).Callback<TestTask>(Action);
        appDbAdaptorMock.Setup(d => d.TestTasks).Returns(dbOpMock.Object);

        var db = new ApplicationDatabaseController(appDbAdaptorMock.Object);
        var task = CreateTestTaskObject(1);
        db.AddTestTask(task);
        Assert.AreEqual(task, assignable);
    }
```

(The test doesn't make a lot of sense yet, but its about the principle)

Then I'd obviously have to create an interface `IApplicationDatabaseAdaptor` so that I could overwrite properties and methods with the mock. I have seen lots of suggestions to do so on SO and other in other places with the reasoning that it enables decoupling.

What do they mean by "enables decoupling"? Why do so many people encourage the use of such interfaces and why is it not considered bad practice to create such interfaces? Especially if I know I am only going to be using them for mocking and nothing else at all.

Comment: What role has the `internal`-modifier in your question? Anyway why should extracting an interface from a class be anything bad? It won´t hurt, but seperates the logic´within your class. Just to add a single advantage.

Comment: I like this question; there is always a grey area that exists when it comes to extent of decoupling, particularly around testing, and although it can be opinion based, I too would like to see the outcome of this discussion!

Comment: @HimBromBeere I mean an interface that I will only ever use myself inside my own Project and that will only have a single implementation. The thing I don't understand is: Why specify an interface with something I have already specified in my class when there will only be a single Implementation? Seems redundant.

Comment: `Especially if I know I am only going to be using them for mocking and nothing else at all.` Do you need to do mocking? If you do need to do mocking, and you don't want to use interfaces, how do you plan to do it? What is your alternative?

Comment: @mjwills Thanks, I realize this now and edited the question. Regarding your second comment: I was under the impression, that it is bad practise to make changes to ones code only for the purpose of testing.

Comment: `Regarding your second comment: I was under the impression, that it is bad practise to make changes to ones code only for the purpose of testing.` Where did you get that impression from? What alternative did they suggest?

Comment: @mjwillis Ok, maybe my wording was to general. I makes sense to change stuff to make it more testable. But if I have, lets say, a property that I would not want to expose, but I need to in order to be able to write tests for the class. Would I then not disregard the principle of information hiding for the benefit of testing?

Comment: If you don't want to expose it, why would it be part of the interface? _Can you give an example of why you might want to do this._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything which is not encapsulated should have and interface defined for few reasons.

1. Unit testing the code using that class by creating mocks.
2. For test driven development where you would mostly define interfaces for sub components.
3. Interface segregation.

if you dont want any of these then go ahead and you can use NSubstitute which will allow you to mock concrete classes too.

Decoupling in real world scenario means

1. you can delay the concrete implementation of components by mocking
   interfaces.
2. You can switch implementations without touching code outside the changed implemention.

Comment: The delaying of implementations seems to be the key part in the scenario I described. Which makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are "coupled" when one class needs another class. So when you declare in interface just one "know" about the other. The main goal is to make all classes as "loose as possible" in the whole application. It makes your code more maintainable and makes it easier and more safe to change code in our application.

But we can think of another good examples of using interfaces:
Image you are writing and app which uses webservices to save its data. Now the customers wants to work offline, because he does not have access to the internet when working with the app but later when he is in the office again.

If you "hide" your communication with the database behind an interface its now easy for you the write a new implementation of the interface to communicate with a local database and you don´t have to rewrite any code: Just create another implementation of the interface and use that.

Another example is that when you use interfaces you can, as you did, mock up data. Image you have a DatabaseProvider which reads data from the database. Now you have a class doing something with that data and you want to test if your class is working correctly. How will you do that?

In the testclass you can mock the data coming from the database and let your class use this to do its magic. Thats only one big advantage of using interfaces for Data access.

Comment: I think it would be worthwhile to explain what would happen between dependant objects in a **closed** system. Surely _everything_ doesn't need to be pulled out into an interface?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with a **closed** system? But you are right, not everything has to pulled out into an interface. How sould i say.. It depends :P
And i think there are many opinions on that topic, and thats good. I´ll just try to explain mine

Comment: Say you have an object `Foo : IFoo`. Inside it, it has some logic that is orchestrated by classes instantiated internally, and never crossing out of the `Foo`. Abstractions of these often bloat constructor dependancies on created interfaces, making your unit tests White-box. Your answer is definitely correct, though. It just can be difficult to pin down what a dependancy should, or shouldn't be in some cases.

Comment: That Interfaces make a lot of sense in distributed applications is out of question. But what I was trying to understand was how it brings advantages in a closed system, except for mocking, like Daniel mentioned.

Comment: `But what I was trying to understand was how it brings advantages in a closed system, except for mocking` Sometimes one advantage is enough. I drink water mainly so I don't dehydrate - for example. That one advantage is enough. :P

Comment: @mjwills It indeed is, that is if It does not simultaneously bring disadvantages.